# Armstrong C code gives a specific output error at 153 in Vs Code on Windows machine

Tags: c, windows, gcc, compiler-errors

I created C code to check armstrong number or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    // Write a program to check if a given number of n digits is Armstrong number or not.

    int n, r, sum = 0, temp, i, p = 0;
    printf("enter the number \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    temp = n;

    for (i = 0; n > 0; i++)
    {
        n = n / 10;
        p++;
    }
    n = temp;
    for (i = 0; n != 0; i++)
    {
        r = n % 10;
        sum = sum + pow(r, p);
        n = n / 10;
    }

    printf("sum is %d\n",sum);

    if (sum == temp)
    {
        printf("%d is a armstrong number", temp);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d is not a armstrong number", temp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When i run this code in Vscode on windows machine it give wrong output at **153 & 1741725**.

enter the number  153 sum is 152 153 is not a armstrong number

snapshot of my vs code

[image]

Except of these two i found all armstrong gives my desired output by running this code.

Is my code is wrong or is it a GCC compiler issue?

When i run this same code on online websites compiler, its run properly. it gives right output as i want.

[image]

I sent this code to my friends to run this code in vs code. They face same problem. **but exception - its gives right output on macos machine vs code**.

So i conclude that its happening on **only on Windows Machine Vs code**.

After more digging I found its maybe happening by using **math.h** header file. I am giving you another code example. Which is basic decimal to binary conversion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
// covert decimal to binary

int main()
{
    int i, n, r, sum = 0, x;
    printf("enter decimal number to convert binary \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; n != 0; i++)
    {
        r = n % 2;
        n = n / 2;
        x = pow(10, i);
        sum = sum + r * x;
        printf("%d \n", sum);
    }
    printf("binary is : %d \n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

And when i run this its gives wrong output at 45

[image]

At the same time when i run using online compiler its gives right output

[image]

My vs code working properly on all others c programs, i completed my entire c programming on vs code.

I just want to know whats the problem behind this?  is my code wrong?  is it error/bug of vscode on windows machine?

Comment: Compilers do have bugs, but if your program is producing the wrong output then the chances of that being the compiler's fault are negligible.  Without reading a single line of it, I tell you that your code is to blame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People seem to have a weird fascination with `pow()`.  Learn this now: `pow()` is not your friend.  Do not use it for integer powers. Especially do not use it if you depend on getting exact integer results.  Use `pow()` only when nothing else will do.

Even if the result of the exponentiation you want to perform is exactly representable as a `double`, the general-purpose exponentiation approach taken by that function might compute a result that differs ever so slightly.  When you convert the result to an integer, the fractional part is truncated.  That's ok for you if there is an error *away* from zero, but if there is even a single-bit error *towards* zero then the subsequent integer conversion will produce a result that is off by one.

For integer math, use repeated multiplication for exponentiation.   You can consider bit-shifting for powers of 2.  This is not only more reliable, but often faster, too.  For example, here's your decimal-to-pseudo-binary program written without `pow()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n, sum = 0;

    printf("enter decimal number to convert binary \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (int i = 0, x = 1; n != 0; i += 1, x *= 10) {
        sum += x * (n % 2);
        n /= 2;
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    }
    printf("binary is : %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

In general, if you are including `math.h` in a program that has no floating-point variables then you are almost certainly doing something wrong.